# Is "Admin" account in apple able to submit the app to apple store?

Tags: iphone, ios

I've an admin account under some team in apple.

I noticing that I have no privileges to access "iTunes Connect".

***Does this means that I can NOT submit applications to Apple Store?***

And What can I do If I couldn't submit the app to apple store?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, admins can't submit apps to the app store in iTunes Connect. Only the Team Agent can do that.